# Are forked processes (bash) subject to server timeout disconnection?

Tags: bash, ssh

If I am working on a remote server (ssh) and I fork a process using bash & operator, will that process be killed if I am booted off the server due to server time-out? I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but would love to know if there are any juicy details.

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs here vs. serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend, but generally when you log out with your "connection program" (e.g. ssh in your case although it could have been rlogin or telnet as well), the shell and children (I think?) will receive a SIGHUP signal (hangup) which will make them terminate when you log out. There are two common ways to avoid this, running the program you want to keep running through `nohup` or `screen`. If the server have some other time limitation on running processes you will have to look into that.

Comment: Right, screen works too, and some platforms have programs that can wrest a non-screened process away from its terminal and attach it to an instance of screen.

Answer (score 2):

bash will send a HUP signal to all background jobs. You can stop this from happening by starting the job with `nohup` (which should have a man page). If it's too late for `nohup`, you can use `disown` to stop the shell from sending a HUP to a job. `disown` is a builtin, so `help disown` will tell you everything you need to know.